# Select empty item in md-autocomplete show [Object Object]

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm trying to add one empty item in my md-autocomplete. It is showed but when i select it in textbox i see [Object Object].

My list of items is as follows

```
 [ 
   {value: '', display: ''},
   {value: 'white', display: 'White'},
   {value: 'green', display: 'Green'},
   {value: 'orange', display: 'Orange'}
 ];
```

Here my codepen with problem

https://codepen.io/Matteo93/pen/PEgWYo

Comment: This seems to be a know old bug. check here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3760

Comment: you could replace it with a space or "No color selected" or so..

Answer (score 2):

I can't realy explain why that is so, but AnguarJs tries to initiate a Object instead of a String. 
If you make a space between your '', AngularJs will understand it as a String and displays it as that.

Btw. I would recomend picking a value every time. I would recomend "nothing" or "default".

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [github.com/angular/material/issues/3760](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3760): on [Apr 10, 2018 it was tagged](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3760#issuecomment-380272213) as "deprecated" signalling that it is "considered old, stale, deprecated, not-core, or too risky".